# PostgreSQL Code Block Returning Cursor or Result Set

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible in Postgres to create a code block which returns a cursor or result set? I want to execute some code with minimal impact on the database ( do not create tables, do not require permissions to create function, etc. ).

I tried something like below but it does not work:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  v_id INT;
  v_name VARCHAR(100);
  tbl record;
  MVE record;
  V_SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(200) ='sample';
  V_SCHEMA_ID INT;
  V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(200) ='';-- IF THE TABLE NAME IS EMPTY, THE COMPLETE SCHEMA WILL BE EXPORTED
  V_TABLE_ID INT = 0;
  V_OBJ_ID INT = 0;
  V_LINE_NO INT = 0;
  V_BUFF TEXT = '';
  V_src_oid oid;
  crs refcursor;
BEGIN
  drop table if exists ddl_table;
  drop SEQUENCE if exists obj_ids;
  drop SEQUENCE if exists line_ids;
  CREATE SEQUENCE obj_ids;
  CREATE SEQUENCE line_ids;
  -- Create temporary table
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ddl_table (
    OBJECT_ID INT,
    TYP INT,
    LINE_NO INT ,
    LINE_TEXT text,
    LINE_PREFIX VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    LINE_SUFFIX VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
  );
  
    ---Check that source_schema exists
  SELECT oid INTO V_src_oid
  FROM pg_namespace
  WHERE nspname = quote_ident(V_SCHEMA_NAME);
  ----TYPE --0 
  INSERT INTO ddl_table (TYP,OBJECT_ID,LINE_NO,LINE_TEXT,LINE_SUFFIX ) values (1,1,1,'bla','');
  OPEN crs FOR SELECT * FROM get_employee_cursor();
  FETCH ALL FROM crs;
  --RETURN query(select * from ddl_table);
END $$;
```

Comment: Where do you want to return the values to?

Comment: [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html): *The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void. It is parsed and executed a single time.*.  So you cannot return anything from a `DO` anonymous function. If you want to do that you will need a regular function.